# ¿cómo puedo almacenar los valores de unos inputs en un array nuevo cada vez que se presione un botón?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un proyecto y quiero saber cómo puedo almacenar los valores de unos inputs en un array, quiero que cada vez que el usuario presione el button estos datos se almacenen en un array, por ejemplo: ingresa los datos, estos se almacenan en un array,luego ingresa otros datos y estos quedan almacenados en un array distinto, pero el array que contiene los primeros datos sigue teniéndolos almacenados, estos nuevos datos se guardarían en otro array nuevo. Si el usuario quiere ingresar otros datos estos datos nuevos se almacenarían en otro array.

```js
let contadorclick= 0; 
function contador(){
 contadorclick = ++contadorclick % 2;
 if (contadorclick==1) {
  ingresar_datos();
 }else{
  ingresar_datos2();
 }
}
let array="";
let array2="";
let n1="";
let n2="";
let n3="";
let n4="";
let n5="";

function ingresar_datos(){
 array=[];
 n1=document.getElementById('producto').value;
 n2=document.getElementById('precio_venta').value;
 n3=document.getElementById('pvu').value;
 n4=document.getElementById('cvut').value;
 n5=document.getElementById('cft').value;
 let incrementar= array.push(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5);
  console.log(array);
}
function ingresar_datos2(){
 array2=[];
 let incrementar= array2.push(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5);
 console.log();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="producto">
 <input type="text" id="precio_venta">
 <input type="text" id="pvu">
 <input type="text" id="cvut"><br>
 <input type="text" id="cft">costos fijos
 <button onclick="contador();"></button>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="proyexto.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es que cada formulario se guarde en el mismo array?

Comment: No, que se guarde un un array distinto

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un array de arrays o forzosamente deben ser distintos?

Comment: Con tal de que se guarde la información que se ingresa en cada click. Para después poder hacer sumas, restas y otras operaciones con los arrays que existen.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de este modo, pero quiero saber si hay alguna forma de no tener que crear otra función que almacene el segundo array, quiero que se cree automáticamente al hacer el segundo click, pero que el primer array siga conteniendo la información.

```js
 let clickCount=0;
 function saySomething() {
      clickCount = ++clickCount % 2;
      
      if (clickCount == 1) ingresar_datos();
      else                 ingresar_datos2();
    }
let array="";
let array2="";
let n1="";
let n2="";
let n3="";
let n4="";
let n5="";

function ingresar_datos(){
 array=[];
 n1=document.getElementById('producto').value;
 n2=document.getElementById('precio_venta').value;
 n3=document.getElementById('pvu').value;
 n4=document.getElementById('cvut').value;
 n5=document.getElementById('cft').value;
 let incrementar= array.push(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5);
  console.log(array);
}
function ingresar_datos2(){
 array2=[];
 n1=document.getElementById('producto').value;
 n2=document.getElementById('precio_venta').value;
 n3=document.getElementById('pvu').value;
 n4=document.getElementById('cvut').value;
 n5=document.getElementById('cft').value;
 let incrementar= array2.push(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5);
 console.log(array);
 console.log(array2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el array de arrays

```
var items = [];
function saySomething() {
        var item =[];
    var n1=document.getElementById('producto').value;
    var n2=document.getElementById('precio_venta').value;
    var n3=document.getElementById('pvu').value;
    var n4=document.getElementById('cvut').value;
    var n5=document.getElementById('cft').value;
        item.push(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5);
        items.push(item);

        console.log(items);
}
```